# Please explain how to interface to a dictionary file from a searchable application

Tags: android, file, search, dictionary

I would appreciate help on how to use a dictionary file to search an application for matching words.  My homework project is to make an existing simple application searchable using a dictionary file containing a few matching words.  I know how to add code to make the app searchable but basically clueless beyond that.  The SearchableDictionary sample code for SDK-7 is rather complex and not well commented (for me anyway) so I am having difficulty right now learning from it.  Please point me to a well-explained tutorial or provide some guidelines if you can.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I learned from SearchableDictionary v2 sample project which uses both database and dictionary file and applied it to my homework project!  The homework requirement does not forbid using database.